# MSSQL slow running query calls

Tags: sql-server, performance, entity-framework

I have weird problem with MSSQL.Normally everything works fine, but like each I dont know 20 query calls or each hour ( I dont know how to determine it ) the single sql call takes really long like 10s where normally it takes less than 1s. Maybe this is something to do with connectionString, Orm EntityFramework that Iam using or maybe some mssql configuration production config ?

How I can make it work so it wont be hanging like this from time to time

Comment: Your query with parameters?

Comment: select * from Patients p join Address a on p.AddressId = a.Id
Result query contains like 20 columns that it.

Comment: Ok. Please provide a `DDL` for your tables and execution plan...

Comment: Also, do you have any index rebuild or statistics calculation jobs set to run, and at what interval?